# Speeding Up A Vue.js Component Under Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Vue.js component which gets a big list of releases from the database, at which point we can use all the lovely reactive list-filtering functionality to drill down to what we're looking for. The problem is that there's a very noticeable lag after page load before the list appears on the page.

Obviously loading the data in via ajax may not be instantaneous, but I thought I might be able to get better results by e.g. getting the data on the server-side with Laravel, and then passing it to the component from its containing Blade template as a prop. Not much luck so far though, again, a noticeable wait for the component to receive and display the data.

Are there any simple approaches for having a Vue component ready to go as quickly as possible? I looked at the prerender-spa-plugin for webpack but I don't know if that would interact properly with the Laravel routing. Likewise server-side rerendering with node seems like it could be more trouble than it's worth.

Has anyone experienced similar issues and found anything like a great solution?

Comment: Well, I guess you might not have many options but improving the db/db-query and/or making the API-Endpoint filterable by parameters (the list-filtering is kinda useless in this case). However, could you provide some sample code on how you did this in the 2nd paragraph?

Answer (score -2):

you have too spot where you could do somethings. 1 on the server. by caching queries or somethings. And the second is on client side. when you handle the received / fetched collection. If you have, lets say 10000 entry, this would take sometime to a: parse the json object, b: create necessary vue components (if you're using vue component for row), and generating corresponding dom. So if you split and handle the recieved data in sized chunk. Vue would update the dom accordingly. and Fill the dom more like a stream. Not always the best approch but working in many case.